# Labels, buttons, and fields not related to data

Tags: html, newmips

Is is possible, and how, to define a space on a from that is not related to a field ?

How to put content in that space, for example a text? a logo? an image? a html text? a link? a button? a html with click=function?

Something like that:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access and edit each page related to a view using HTML editor in Newmips Studio.

We encourage to place static elements in a  tag in order to be able to move them with the designer.

For the moment, you need to add all resources manually (accessing Git repository). A graphical interface to manage resources (images, videos, etc.) is planned in version 2.5 (end of year 2017).

Comment: I am not after fancy object. Only a static text like a company name that will be the same for all the data. I added apicture  in my question.